# IntelliJ does not launch Flutter app with Chrome as expected

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, launch

My IDE offers three environments to start my Flutter app with. Unfortunately, whenever I try to launch the app with Chrome, Edge opens. In console at startup, Chrome is mentioned but Edge is started instead

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
```

I once had Chrome installed, removed it and re-installed it later. First tries to launch with Chrome where while Chrome was not present (but stil in IntelliJ's list).

My OS is Windows.

Is there a place where the launch environments are configured in IntelliJ?

[image: Runtime environments available]

Comment: please try steps from https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3503#issuecomment-815843356 - does it make things any better? if not, please report the issue to https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues

Comment: please also try running `flutter doctor --verbose` - what is the `CHROME_EXECUTABLE` set to?

Comment: [√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • CHROME_EXECUTABLE = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe

Comment: The IntelliJ bug report describes my issue (despite OS differs) but the solution there does not solve it.

Comment: `CHROME_EXECUTABLE` must be the issue